Can you find the limit of $e_n = \log_n (n+1)$ without using L'Hospital's Rule?
Usually, one would solve it like that:
$$\log_n (n+1) = \frac{\ln (n+1)}{\ln (n)}$$
Let $f(n) = \ln (n+1)$ and $g(n) = \ln (n)$. Obviousy, $f'(n) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $g'(n) = \frac{1}{n}$, thus:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln (n+1)}{\ln (n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = 1$$
But can this be solved without using L'Hospital's Rule?

You can write $$\log_n (n+1) = \frac{\ln (n+1)}{\ln (n)}=\frac{\ln (n(1+\frac 1n))}{\ln (n)}=1+\frac{\ln (1+\frac 1n)}{\ln (n)}$$
and the last term clearly goes to zero

But the bottom term goes to infinity. So although $\ln (1 + \frac{1}{n}) \to 0$, we have the problem that $\ln (n) \to \infty$.

@anon That's no problem, as $0/\infty=0$. If you don't think that's rigorous enough, use the squeeze theorem.
